# Automate document/image upload (to a website) process to test a Rest API (Document Verification)

Tags: python, rest, image-processing

I have to test a RestAPI. The RestAPI basically has a document verification logic. So I have to upload a document/image from my local machine and run the API. Its good if I have to test just 1 or 2 images/docs but what if I have to test 50-60 docs/images. How can I automate this thing? I am currently learning Python, so it would be really great if I can automate it through Python Script. Does anyone know about this ????

Comment: could you please elaborate, i cant understand question, what and how exactly you want to test? it is not clear what kind of verification you mean, could you add algorithm or code?

Comment: For now, we can consider that the API will convert image to text, and for it to happen I need to upload the images. All I want is how to automate the process of uploading the images and storing the result.